# CSS transitions jerky because of lazy loading during animation. How to avoid this?

Tags: jquery, css, html, reveal.js

My problem is that I have a long [reveal.js presentation](http://akaleeroy.github.io/) where I'd like to lazy load images and YouTube and Vimeo videos. When the content is loading, slide transitions are jerky.

This is not so much of a problem on powerful computers with good broadband connections, but it's quite a show-stopper on smartphones.

I've read that I should **Avoid DOM changes or other callbacks firing during animation:**
[image: Tapping into Mobile UI with HTML5]

How can I time the lazy loading so that it interferes less with the beautiful smooth transitions of [reveal.js](http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/)?

Comment: As that plugin looks like it uses CSS transitions (i.e. as smooth as it gets), it sounds like you need to start pre-loading all images as soon as the page loads. By the time anyone clicks the first button, they would *hopefully* already all be loaded. This may be a problem for videos though,

Comment: ...and +1 for a pretty cool looking website :)

Comment: What do you use for lazy loading?  You may be able to preload the first couple of slides and then keep preloading a slide ahead so by the time they click on the next button it should have already loaded

Comment: Ti-ai batut destul de mult capul cu prezentarea aceea si functiile, insa, daca imi permiti, la ce o vei folosi? Este o prezentare unde tu vei putea controla mediul de vizualizare ? Browser, hardware s.a.? Sau este un portofoliu de prezentare?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I think videos are the main concern here, maybe I should load only posters... What would be a good way to do that?
  
[@]Pete For lazy loading I asked the wonderful developer of reveal.js to implement it. Here it is in the dev branch: [lazy loading support for video #793 · bbd596e · hakimel/reveal.js](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/commit/bbd596e434969b446c2dff0929e3117285974fc4)
  
[@]Alin Ar trebui sa fie un portofoliu de prezentare, in mod ideal as vrea sa ruleze pe cat mai multe deviceuri.

Answer (score 1):

First of all be careful with the tags when trying to reply to someone in a comment, something like [@]SouPress isn’t working, I didn’t get a notification when you tagged me and neither did the rest. That’s probably why you didn’t get any answers. So, using CSS like that will not grant your wish of working smoothly on many devices, especially if your targeting Romanian Population. Most of the home PC’s in the country will not provide a nice experience while viewing your portfolio and a lot of companies work with out of date browsers that will not support your transitions.

On the other hand, like @trueblueaussie said, css transitions are as smooth as they get.

One thing I could recommend is that you use those videos to preload the images in between with a click event, also (though it’s not part of the best practices) to preload a video you could simulate two clicks to play and then pause.

To mask everything you could make a preload interface to delay showing the website for a number of x- seconds and let the website load as much as possible in that amount of time.
Though, unfortunately, you are at the mercy of the client’s internet connection and his consciousness when it comes to his experience with not-updated browsers

Best of luck.

**RO:**
Salut, in primul rand ai grija cum faci tag-urile cand raspunzi persoanelor, [@]SouPress nu merge, eu nu am primit notificare ca mi-ai raspuns si nici ceilalti. Motiv pentru care, probabil, nu ai mai primit raspunsuri. In alta ordine de idei, din pacate, folosirea CSS-ului in felul acela nu iti va indeplini dorinta de a rula pe cat mai multe device-uri, mai ales daca publicul target este din Romania. Marea majoritate a pc-urilor nu vor oferi o experienta placuta cand vor vizualiza portofoliul si din pacate, multe firme ruleaza cu browsere out of date care nu vor suporta website-ul.

In alta oridine de idei, asa cum a spus si TrueBlueAussie, tranzitiile cu CSS sunt cat se poate de smooth.

Ce iti pot recomanda este sa te folosesti de acele video pentru a face preload la imaginile dintre ele on click event si in acelasi timp (desi nu intra la best practices) pentru a face preload si la video, poti simula doua click event-uri pe ele pentru a da play si pause...

Pentru a face toata chestia cat mai smooth si sa o maschezi, poti face un preload interface care sa dureze un numar de x secunde in care site-ul sa se incarce cat mai mult posibil.

Insa, din pacate, acum esti la mana conexiunii clientului si a constiintei acestuia cand vine vorba de experienta sa cu browserele.

Best of luck.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment with more than one mention. Or [something](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work "WTF."). I was in a hurry, sorry I left you out. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Well, best of luck with your portfolio ;)